# Catalog Price Rules: "Stop Further Rules Processing' (not cart rules) - how does this work? M1

Tags: rules, catalog-rules

Catalog Price Rules: "Stop Further Rules Processing" (not cart rules) - how does this work?

So, How does "Stop Further Rules Processing" work?

- does this work in product level? set a flag: stop further rules processing only for the "affected" products by the current rule? (so: all rules, but products are affected only once by the first rule touching them)
- Does it mean: stop processing of any other rule. So no rules with lower prior and no other rules with the same prior (so: only the 1 rule)
- Does this mean: stop processing of all other rules with a lower prior - but do finish all rules with the same prior? (so: only 1 rule + the rules with the same prior)

Example situation

- 2 rules 1 with PRIO 10 other with PRIO 2. Rule 1 has stopped further processing: what does this do?
- 10 rules all with PRIO 10 and 15 other with PRIO 2. The first rule of 10 rules with PRIO 10 has stopped further processing: what does this do?

Reference is taken from Magento

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

> If you want to stop the processing of other rules after this rule has
>   been applied, set Stop Further Rules Processing to “Yes.” This
>   safeguard prevents customers from receiving multiple discounts for the
>   same product.

I am thrown off by the part "for the same product" which hints at some kind of rule stopping on the product level: read stop further rules processing is only applicable to the 1st product that it matches And does not match a second rule) however a product not affected by the first rule, may be affected by the 2nd rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be given here

> Stop Further Rules Processing - In the instance that multiple price
>   rules are being applied at once for the same products, setting this
>   option to Yes will prevent further rules from applying to the products
>   (so the products aren't being double discounted). Keep in mind it is
>   the priority field that will determine in what order they are being
>   applied.

https://support.zero1.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/215298048-Magento-Catalog-Price-Rules

Answer (score 1):

1. Catalog rules are the rules which can control and affect the price on the order placing items from our store.
2. Priority means the order to follow the rules to apply.
3. That means That priority given rules will be applied to the website to the products to make the orders.
4. For example, If you have 10 rules in your store, If you give priority 1 to the 5th rule and give the options as prevent remaining rules, Then the 5th rule only will be affected in the store.